# Get the current date/time in Ruby as string without delimiters?

Tags: ruby

Is there any good way to get the current date/time in Ruby as a string without separators, not having to use `Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d')`, etc.?

The output I'm looking for is something like "20151002112001" or similar, with all digits and no separators, human-readable form, not Unix time.

Comment: What do you mean by "i.e. not having to do `Time.now.strftime(...)`"? Isn't that the natural way of formatting a date/time in a specific way in Ruby?

Comment: What I mean is "give me the date + time without having to manually specify all the parts I am interested in". I.e. "use sensible defaults". Yes, that is the normal way to format a date/time in Ruby, but in this use case, I feel it forces me to provide too much details. I just want it as a string (to be able to create an Elastic index including it).

Comment: I wouldn't say there are any "sensible defaults" to be honest. Some people will only want time down to the second, and some down to the millisecond, etc. Even if there's a default which happens to do what you want, I'd far rather see it explicitly in code, as that makes it clear what you're expecting. It's not "too much details" - it's "a clear expression of what I expect" IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet - fair enough. I understand your point, providing a formatting string makes it clearer to the reader what is going on. OTOH, not having to write out that format string (and remember which one of month/minute is %m and %M) felt convenient to me.

Comment: It's convenient when you're writing it - but in my experience code is *read* more often than it's *written*, so I try to write my code to be as clear to the reader as possible, even if it takes me longer to write. (When reading the code, I'd *assume* the author had all the format specifiers correct, unless I had a reason to doubt it - and a string with the appropriate bits would make it clear.)

Comment: Agree to your first statement, of course. **But** are you really sure that `Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")` is so much more readable than `Time.now.to_formatted_s(:number)`? :) I mean, saying "give me a number-formatted string"... that's quite a lot more expressive than a dozen % codes.

Comment: Put it this way: I'm not a Ruby developer, but I could guess what the first one does without checking... I'd have to consult the documentation for the second one. I don't know what the granularity of `Time.now` is in Ruby - in Java the granularity is either milliseconds or nanoseconds depending on the type you use; in .NET it's 100ns. How much of that granularity should I expect "give me a number-formatted string to give"?

Comment: Good points. In my context, all people reading this code are Ruby developers. (and those that perhaps wouldn't be wouldn't be developers at all :) So, YMMV. I agree that "for universally understandable code", strftime may be convenient. But it's not *idiomatic Ruby code* in my eyes.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call `20151002112001` human-readable. We're not good at parsing long strings of numbers into a date and time. Something like `20151002_112001`, where a delimiter helps define the fields is more common. Code, once told how to parse it, won't care, but humans trying to make sense of it need help, hence the ability to format into more readable forms.

Comment: Excellent point. `20151002_112001` is definitely much more human-readable than the first form. Then - since the ActiveSupport method gives me the first value, that's "good enough" for me. :P It's still more readable than a Unix epoch timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that by using [Active Support](https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport/versions/4.2.4), this can be [easily done](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Time/Conversions.html):

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/time/conversions'
Time.now.to_formatted_s(:number) # => "20151002112419"
```

Since I already depend on Active Support, this turned out to be the quickest and easiest way to get this done by far.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `.to_i` on a Time object to get a number representing [Unix-time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

You can convert Date or DateTime objects to Time with `.to_time`. For example:

```
string = "#{Date.today.to_time.to_i}"
# "1443769200"
```

If you need to get certain attributes but don't like strftime, you can use methods of [Date](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html). For example, you might do something like

```
date = Date.today
string = "#{date.year}-#{date.month}-#{date.day}"
# "2015-10-2"
```

This all works without Active Support, but you still need to `require 'date'`.

Comment: Thanks Max! However, I am after something "human readable" in this case (which my question indicated: date/year/month/hour/minute/second - it wasn't spelled out, but it was implicit in my example)

Comment: You almost certainly *wouldn't* want to use `"#{date.year}#{date.month}#{date.day}"` as is, precisely because the output would end up being "2015102" today... instead of "20151002". While that's unambiguous today, what does "2015112" mean - November 2nd or January 12th?

Comment: @JonSkeet you're right; good catch; i added some dashes to the string in my answer, which addresses this.

Comment: But leaves it looking in a format which is *nearly* ISO-8601 but not quite. Basically, when you're writing a machine-readable date format you should always include appropriate 0-padding.

Comment: Agree, and if you want ISO-8601 you *shouldn't* be writing a format string yourself but instead use `require 'time';Time.now.iso8601`. However, I specifically said I wanted "all digits" so this is not really a perfect answer.

Comment: @PerLundberg: Again, even ISO-8601 isn't exactly one format. There's extended or basic, with or without separators... but at least it's a good clue as to what's meant (and hopefully it's easily found in the documentation...)

Comment: @JonSkeet, carefil with the details, are we not? ;)

Comment: @PerLundberg: After a lot of experience with date/time oddities, you learn to be careful :)